# Filter on a has many through connection

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4, rails-activerecord

I have a worker who has many hours and many jobs through hours

```
class Worker < ActiveRecord::Base

has_many :hours
has_many :jobs, :through => :hours

....
```

I am trying to get some hours where I sort on the date property of a job. Cant figure out the syntax

```
hours.includes(:jobs).where("jobs.date >= ?", d).each do |h|
  sum = sum + h.total_hours_worked
end
```

Keeps saying Unknown column name 'jobs.date'

I thought includes would not be necessary since it is a through connection but cant make it work with or without. I tried singular names too, no luck

Comment: Where's `sum` defined?

Answer (score 0):

Got it

```
hours.includes(:job).where("jobs.date >= ?", d).references(:job).each do |h|
  sum = sum + h.total_hours_worked
end
```

Answer (score 0):

```
hours.joins(:jobs).where("jobs.date >= ?", d).sum(:total_hours_worked)
```

Comment: Please add explanation as well along with the code, to make it understandable how it will solve the problem.